# Solving for $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in $5\sin(x) = \lambda(2\sin(x)-3) + \mu 2\cos(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve for $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in the following equation:
> $$5\sin(x) = \lambda(2\sin(x)-3) + \mu 2\cos(x)$$

I have tried:
$$
 5\sin(x) = 2\lambda \sin(x) -3\lambda+2\mu \cos(x)
$$
Comparing the coefficient of $\sin x$:

$$
 2\lambda = 5
$$
$$
 \lambda = \frac{5}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's $$(2\lambda-5)\sin{x}+2\mu\cos{x}=3\lambda$$ or since the case $2\lambda-5=\mu=0$ is impossible,
$$\frac{2\lambda-5}{\sqrt{(2\lambda-5)^2+4\mu^2}}\sin{x}+\frac{2\mu}{\sqrt{(2\lambda-5)^2+4\mu^2}}\cos{x}=\frac{3\lambda}{\sqrt{(2\lambda-5)^2+4\mu^2}}.$$
Now, take $$\frac{2\lambda-5}{\sqrt{(2\lambda-5)^2+4\mu^2}}=\cos\alpha$$ and
$$\frac{2\mu}{\sqrt{(2\lambda-5)^2+4\mu^2}}=\sin\alpha.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Michael thank mate

Comment: @LipunPanda Is the question to find $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that the LHS and RHS are equal for all values of $x$?

Comment: @TobyMak . There aren't any. If $x=0$ then $0=-3\lambda +2\mu.$ If $x=\pi$ then $0=-3\lambda-2\mu.$ Together these imply $\lambda=0.$ But if $x=\pi/2$ then $5=-\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$f=5\sin(x) - 2\lambda \sin(x) +3\lambda-2\mu \cos(x)$$ If it is possible, it would zero for any $x$ and, in particular, for small angles.

Using Taylor, we have
$$f=(3 \lambda -2 \mu )+(5-2 \lambda ) x+\mu  x^2+\left(\frac{\lambda }{3}-\frac{5}{6}\right) x^3-\frac{\mu 
   x^4}{12}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ The even term show $\mu=0$. Replacing, what is left is
$$f=3 \lambda +(5-2 \lambda ) x+\left(\frac{\lambda }{3}-\frac{5}{6}\right) x^3+O\left(x^5\right)$$ It is impssible to cancels all the coefficients.

Comment: These values do not work when you graph the functions.